# jQuery/PHP: How to stop HTML form from submitting?

Tags: php, jquery, html

How do I use **jQuery** to validate the user name and password and then process accordingly?

Here is my form:

```
<form action="registration_form.php" method="post" name="register_form">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." name="email" required="required"/>
    <br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password..." name="pwd" required="required"/>
    <br>
    <label>Re-enter Password</label>
    <input id="re_pwd" type="password" placeholder="Renter your password..." name="re_pwd" required="required"/>
    <br>  
    <button>register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: u can use preventDefault jquery function to stop submit the form and after validation can submit the form using javascript.

Comment: I have used this jQuery code. But, it didn't work. `            $('button').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("test message");
            });`

Comment: After a submit, you can disable the Submit button with Javascript and as @AbhikChakraborty mentioned use the `preventDefault()` to stop the form submission and then you can use a javascript submission once the fields are all validated correctly

Comment: give an id to your element and then use $("#buttonid").click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an onsubmit in the form tag and have a javascript function return false if it does not pass validation, but remember to always validate on the back end as well as the front end

```
<form action="registration_form.php" method="post" name="register_form" onsubmit="return validate();">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." name="email" required="required"/>
        <br>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input id="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password..." name="pwd" required="required"/>
        <br>
        <label>Re-enter Password</label>
        <input id="re_pwd" type="password" placeholder="Renter your password..." name="re_pwd" required="required"/>
        <br>  
        <button>register</button>
    </form>

<script>
function validate(){
  if(your validation passes){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="registration_form.php" method="post" name="register_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

If you have a JavaScript function `validateForm` that returns a Boolean (true/false) value, replacing your first line with this will only submit the form if it passes the test.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Should I write my entire validation in the function validateForm() ?

Comment: Yeah. It can call other functions, so long as it eventually returns a value.

Comment: Thank you to you too, for your humble help.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you already accepted answer, here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/LVzry/1/

It's not perfect but it should point you in the right direction.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    if ($('span.error').length > 0) {
        alert('Please fix the form errors before submitting');


    } else if ($("#pwd").val() !== $("#re_pwd").val()) {
        alert("Your passwords are not the same");

    } else if ($("#pwd").val() === "" || $("input[type='email']").val() === "") {
        alert("please enter name and password");



    } else if (!emailReg.test($("input[type='email']").val()) || !passReg.test($("input[type='pwd']").val())) {
        alert("Make sure that your name and password are properly formatted.");
        $("input[type='pwd']").after('<span class="error">Form Error</span>');


    } else {
        $.post("registration_form.php", $('form').serialize(), function () { // post form data
            //do something after submission
        });
    }
});
```